# Removing artefact from dataset: long discontinuities/persistent "spike"

Tags: matlab, data-processing, artifact

Maybe someone can help me? Some artifacts are introduced in the dataset recorded during my experiment. In more details, continuous spikes shifts a large part of the data to higher or lower values.

Lets say, the data are smoothly increasing from 1 to 1000 between t=0 and t=9. At t=10, the data abruptly decrease to 400 and then smoothly increase from 400 to 1400 between t=11 and t=20. At t=21, the data abruptly change again... This process (most probably due to a malfunction of the recorder) is repeated all along the dataset and is completely random in time (no specific frequency) but the shifts always have the same intensity.

I tried to use various filters in matlab (hampel, medfilt1,...) but they do not remove these big "jumps". I could do it by hand (selecting each portion one after the other) but I have several very large dataset and there are too many of these artifacts.

I was wondering if someone had the same problem and find out a solution. I thank you in advance for your help!

Barbara

Comment: Usually medfilt1 removes the kind of jumps you mentioned. What sizes of window for the filter did you try?

Comment: if you provide sample data, I can help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when processing signal from accelerator - there were shifts equal to the dynamic range of the sensor. All you have to do is take first derivate of data and find peaks by a fixed threshold. Then you can replace these peaks with the mean value of derivatives just before and after the peak.